# Happen to (in questions)

Tags: translation, meaning, phrase

I'm aware that you can use 正好 or 碰巧 to express low probability in statements, equivalent to English "happen to" .

我正好是有你要的那种啤酒。

我发现他碰巧就是我的一个远亲。

How can you use this same idea in a question?

"Do you happen to have an eyeglass screwdriver?"

Edit: I want to express that I'm aware the probability of them having the [unusual item] is low, but that I'm asking anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you wouldn't translate *happen* in questions like the one you proposed.

---

But, if you really wanted to - the best equivalent I can think of for doing this would be by adding:

> 顺便问一下

at the beginning of a question.

So your question would end up being something like:

> 顺便问一下，你有没有眼镜护理螺丝刀呢？

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to have a spaceship?
你不会正好有一艘飞船吧？

Answer (score 0):

Translate:- "Do you happen to have an eyeglass screwdriver?"

In this particular situation where the serendipitous element of "accidental / surprise" is absent, ((which "happen to", 碰巧, (as 碰, "to meet, bump into"), would imply)), I would prefer to use 也许, (maybe, perhaps) as an interrogative.

Perhaps in reply to the question, 正好 could be used sensibly.

So, the question:- 你*也许*有眼镜螺丝刀吗？ -- "Maybe / perhaps you have eyeglass screwdriver?"

To answer:- 我*正好*有一个  -- （I happened to have one)

Answer (score -1):

We use 正好 more in daily conversation between friends or family talking cause this is not a word that formally.

So we would probably not use this word to someone we don't that familiar with.